# Spam in (or as) a username

Tags: discussion, spam

A new user has shown up with what appears to be a "I've never seen this one before, but I know spam when I smell it" **username**, rather than spamming links in answers. I can't recall any mention of "not spamming" in the username rules - I can't even recall what rules there even are for choosing a username. But I know spam when I smell it. Having commented without any effect, is there a process for flagging such things, or is this a loophole that will have to await a rules change to deal with?

[How should I insulate my workshop](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/90254/how-should-i-insulate-my-workshop)

Comment: Found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61249/133749) on [meta.StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: So: A loophole full of reconstituted meat. Ah, well.

Comment: The user probably had no intention of spamming at all. Many, many accounts like it on SO, as linked in the post @Tester101 referred to: http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the user's profile and questions they are asking on other sites, along with the web page they are linking to, I believe this falls short of the typical spam we would remove. The url doesn't appear to be the focus of any of their questions, but more of a personal reference, and the content of their questions aren't stepping over the line of the [self promotion](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) policy. To create a policy about url's in a user name, I believe that needs to move up to the [SE meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Tester101 has found an existing MSE thread that shows the dead horse to have been beaten, sliced, and packed in cans, so I guess we're stuck with it.

Comment: Yep: "You're free to put anything you like (as long as it isn't pronographic or otherwise offensive)"